# Matlab 3D matrix extension

Tags: matlab, matrix, extend

I have 2x2x1 3d matrix (val) in MATLAB such:

```
val(:,:,1) =

   195   1386
   27   10

val(:,:,2) =

   196   138
   217   102
```

and I want to add

```
val(:,:,3) = 

   196   138
   217   102
   217   102.
```

As usual, Matlab gives dimension mismatch error. What should I do to my val matrix before adding 3rd (3x2) matrix?

Comment: What should happen with the original 2x2x2 matrix? How to fill the missing row? by 0s or by NaNs?

Comment: A matrix of that size is simply not possible. Each slice has to have the same size. Maybe a cell of 2d matrices is a solution? What do you expect?

Comment: Okey if it is not possible with resizing matrix, I try to do it with cell.

Answer (score 1):

Given your original array:

```
val(:,:,1) = [
   195   1386
   27   10 ];
val(:,:,2) = [
   196   138
   217   102 ];
```

you need to define a third row. Fill it with something, for example with `NaN`:

```
val(end+1,:,:) = NaN;
```

That way, dimensions will match when you add the new slice:

```
val(:,:,3) = [
   196   138
   217   102
   217   102 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array cannot have empty spots.

For changing dimensions, you should consider using struct or cell.